# Open a Google Doc when the user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have created a html output that provides the user with a button, on click I would like to open a Google Document by ID. The ID is currently a variable within my google script therefore I have the `onclick` running a function in my .gs file. However I am unsure on the method to then open the document, alternatively how I could pass the id to my HTML and open the document directly from my onclick.

**HTML**

```
<input id=nxtBtn type="button" value="Next" onClick="google.script.run.openDoc()";/>
```

**gs**

```
function openDoc(id){
    Logger.log("openDoc: " +id)
    // open google doc script here......???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the link in the HTML part of the script.

### HTML

```
<input id=nxtBtn type="button" value="Next" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(openLink).getDocUrl()";/>
```

### Your HTML scripts

```
function openLink(url) {
  window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

### gs

```
function getDocUrl() {
  var id = "You somehow get your id";
  return DriveApp.getFileById(id).getUrl();
}
```